# Initializing weights in a 3 layer neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

So I'm learning the SIMPLEST way to code a neural network, one that can be modified in many ways depending on what you want, basically like a template. I found i am trask's 11 line neural network code, and the weight initialization makes perfect sense:

```
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1
```

However, when I look at it for his extended 3 layer network, it looks like this:

```
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
```

I would understand if syn1 was a bit different, but BOTH are now different! He doesn't explain it, only gives a comment saying, "randomly initialize our weights with mean 0."

Can someone explain to me the mathematical reasoning behind this? Go full crazy if you want, I'm a math person since 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by different, you are referring to the arguments of `np.random.random()`, then it is because you are creating weights with different shapes/dimensions. In this example (which ignores biases), you are trying to go from an input of dimension 3 to an output of dimension 1. With one layer, you require the shape `(3,1)`. For two layers, you need shapes `(3,n)` and `(n,1)`, where `n` is any integer. This is just to ensure that matrix multiplication is valid. Here `n = 4` has been chosen as the hidden layer dimension.

Comment: Yes, that answers it! Thanks!